# Фон из трёх изображений в ie

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Нужен блок, фон которого составляют несколько изображений. Логично сделать так:

```
background:url('a.png') top no-repeat,url('b.png') bottom no-repeat
```

Но IE не воспринимает такой фон и изображает его одним повторяющимся изображением. Как можно сделать такой фон кроссбраузерным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ie тупой, делай в 3 div-a

Comment: Согласен!
п.с. верстальщики уже давно начали отказываться от ie6, потому как технологии двигаются в перед, приходится все больше и больше хачить чтоб все пахало валидно, просто ставят заглушку: типа для просмотра сайта ваш браузер устарел, и предлагается качнуть другой.

Comment: @RedMonkey, так и думал сначала, но решил проверить, вдруг есть попроще решение.

@FreeMast, я на своих сайтах так и делаю, но здесь заказчик настаивает на ие.

Comment: заказчик тупой, делай в 3 div-a  
=)